# Read Elements from XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader

I have response from web service and my code looks like following

```
using (WebResponse response2 = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();                   
    }
}
```

Now I have my complete response to string soapResult.

My XML looks like following:

```
soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GetResponse xmlns="http://ws.design.americaneagle.com">
     <GetResult>
        <Distance>0</Distance>
        <ID>100</ID>
        <Name>Wisconsin</Name>
        <Code>WI</Code>
        <Address1>202 Las COlinas</Address1>
    </GetResult>
  </GetResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I want to read ID, Name, and Address1 from the above XML.

How to achieve this? I am new to XML in c#.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn about LINQ to XML.

Comment: Cannot use LINQ. Need pure XML technology.

Comment: The web service provider should have given you an XSD if applicable.

Comment: @Santosh: What does that even mean? LINQ is just C# functions.

Comment: @karritos What we can do with XSD?

Comment: @Santosh The XSD file describes the response of the web service, 
If that file exists, you can generate the code and then read it very easily.

Comment: @karritos can you show me or give me some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq.  For testing I'm reading from a file (instead of a webresponse) so you have to make slight changes to go back to your original code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(FILENAME))
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(rd);

                XElement response = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "GetResponse").FirstOrDefault();
                XNamespace ns = response.GetDefaultNamespace();

                var data = response.Descendants(ns + "GetResult").Select(x => new {
                    distance = (int)x.Element(ns + "Distance"),
                    id = (int)x.Element(ns + "ID"),
                    name = (string)x.Element(ns + "Name"),
                    code = (string)x.Element(ns + "Code"),
                    addresss = (string)x.Element(ns + "Address1")
                }).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Xmldocument . With use root statement . It's very to use .. read about it .. or use XPath.  Also read about it!

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your XML in [XML to Sharp](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) and got this:

```
            using System;
            using System.Xml.Serialization;
            using System.Collections.Generic;

            namespace Xml2CSharp
            {
                [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetResult", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                public class GetResult
                {
                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Distance", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public string Distance { get; set; }

                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public string ID { get; set; }

                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public string Name { get; set; }

                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public string Code { get; set; }

                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address1", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public string Address1 { get; set; }
                }

                [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetResponse", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                public class GetResponse
                {
                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GetResult", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public GetResult GetResult { get; set; }

                    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
                    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
                }

                [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
                public class Body
                {
                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GetResponse", Namespace = "http://ws.design.americaneagle.com")]
                    public GetResponse GetResponse { get; set; }
                }

                [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
                public class Envelope
                {
                    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
                    public Body Body { get; set; }

                    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
                    public string Soap { get; set; }

                    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
                    public string Xsi { get; set; }

                    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
                    public string Xsd { get; set; }
                }
            }
```

Then you have to deserialize it.

```
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope result;

            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```